# Trying to protect a specific sheet in work book but get 40036 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening a specific file set as wb, it is reading the sheet thus my msgbox as a check but when I come to protect the same sheet I get the compiler error.

I have tried numerous methods to complete this task but none work, such as activating the specific sheet "Front Page" selecting it etc but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

```
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WSName As String
    Dim URNName As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= "\\Folder\1718 list of SD(s) trainees.xlsm"

    Worksheets("pivot").Activate

    LastRow = 240

    For i = 4 To 240

        WSName = Cells(i, 6)
        URNName = Cells(i, 7)

        ' Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\Folder\Annex G Usage\" & WSName & " " & URNName & " SD(s)17-18 Statement of Grant Usage.xlsm"
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\Folder\Annex G Usage\" & WSName & " " & URNName & " SD(s)17-18 Statement of Grant Usage.xlsm")

        MsgBox " Name" & Cells(10, 3)

        ' wb.Sheets("Front Page").Activate

        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOReadyToHelp", _
                            DrawingObjects:=True, _
                            Contents:=True, _
                            Scenarios:=True, _
                            AllowSorting:=True, _
                            AllowFiltering:=True, _
                            AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: And you're getting that error on your `ActiveSheet.Protect` line? Also I'd edit your post to redact that password, if it's something that you actually use for your files...

Comment: After opening the workbook, try to protect it manually and see if it works. I suspect there is something corrupt on the sheet that is causing the issue.

Comment: The error is on ActiveSheet.Protect line, password showing is not the one I'll be using. I have tried manually protecting the work sheet and that works fine. Any other ideas chaps?

Comment: In the immediate window, and with the workbook open, try running this: Worksheets("pivot").protect
If that works then start adding arguments until it fails

Comment: Thanks folks for all your advise, I recorded a macro to protect the sheet and that failed to work as part of the large sub routine. Had to resort to manually protecting the sheet in the 400 files to get task completed in time.